# How to stop slider slides in $.each loop after results goes finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a slides which have shows 4 property images with their description that are appended in $.each loop. But right now, i have only 8 results to show in slider.

so problem is the, when result are successfully show then slides are going blank, but i want stop these slides after finishing the resultant slides.

**Here is my ajax response**

```
jQuery.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'<?php echo base_url("site/landing/get_work_places"); ?>',
       data:{ city_name:city},
       dataType: 'json', 

       success:function(data)
       {

                 var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);  

                 var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

           if (json=="")
           {
              $('#work_hider').hide();

                  // alert("no results found");
           }else
           {                  

               $.each(json, function(key, data) 
                 {
                   // All the variables from the database containing the post data.
                      var product_id=data.product_id;
                      var product_name=data.product_title;
                       var product_image=data.product_image;
                       var work_price = data.price_perhour;
                       var work_address = data.address;

                     $("#work-carousel").append('<li class="span3"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="<?php echo base_url('rental'); ?>/'+product_id+'"><img src="'+product_image+'" alt=""></a></div><div class="caption"><h2>'+work_price+'</h2></div><div class="caption"><h4>'+product_name+'</h4>  <p>'+work_address+'</p></div></li>');



                  });

                for (i = 0; i <= $('.span3').length / 4; i++) {
                $('.span3').slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4).wrapAll('<div class="item"><ul id="work_property">');
              }


          }
       }
      });

      // slider ajax ends

    });
```

**Here is slider HTML slider code**

```
    <div class="work_carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="work-carousel">
            <div class="item active">
                    <ul class="thumbnails" id="work_property">


                    </ul>
              </div>

        </div>

        <div class="control-box" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">                            
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>      
</div>
</div>
```

**Here is a pic for slider with their result**

[image]

**Here is a pic for slider with finished result**

[image]

**Note:** 1 Slide = 4 Resultant images, and i have fixed limit with 8 results in SQL query so i want to running only 2 slides then stop theses slides.

Please suggest me how can i stop these slides after finishing results, Thanks :)

Comment: Try this - Instead of $('#work_hider').hide(); - Use this - $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: false
}); That will make the auto sliding stop because there no Milliseconds added and will never slider next.

Comment: not working, its look like it also append a blank slide with it

Comment: $('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: false }); is only applies, when ajax have no any response but i have some results..

Comment: Then count interval * no of slides, and setinterval to that time and then stop slider by executing interval to false. If that makes sense.

Comment: its working,thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
   var totalItems = $('.item').length;
var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
$('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');

$('.work_carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
});

$('.work_carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;

   if(currentIndex >= 3){

  $('#work_property').attr("id")="newid";

   }
});
```